# PyMongo .. collection.find_one() .. error

Tags: mongodb

I am using PyMongo version 3.2.2 and trying to make a simple query:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
connection = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = connection.terra
acris = db.acris
first_item = acris.find_one()
print(first_item["DOCUMENT ID])
```

Nothing happens, it waits forever. So then when I do CTRL -C I get the following traceback error:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
File "first_pymongo_app", line 12, in <module>
acris.find_one()

gotit = waiter.acquire(True, timeout)
```

The code works for the first 4 lines and fails at the 5th line = acris.find_one()

How can I find this error, so that PyMongo returns the first document/object value with the key specified in the collection?

Also, note that this code works:

```
print(acris.find())
```

It returns this object:

```
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x103324be0>
```

Comment: `find_one()` is not a shell method. In the shell you need to use `findOne()`. Are you using any language driver?

Comment: 'findOne()' worked. Thank you!  When I use PyMongo I can't get 'find_one()' to work

Comment: Thank you!  'findOne()' worked in mongo shell.   However, When I use PyMongo I can't get 'find_one()' to work. It just sits there and waits, nothing happens. Could it be that PyMongo is just super slow?

Comment: Please edit your question with the code that doesn't work.

Comment: If I `CTRL -C` I get a traceback with this message at the end of it: `gotit = waiter.acquire(True, timeout)`

Comment: Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37685782/edit) link on your question to provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I removed the full traceback, and just kept the last statement of the traceback to keep the code short (mvce)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114059/discussion-between-user3100115-and-user3062459).

Comment: make sure that your mongo server is running! you can check that via `lsof -i :27017`